avoid intersections of instances when changing their size
there is a simple bunch of nodes that allows you to avoid intersections of instances, but if scale = 1, and if you set a random value, then intersections appear



Could you detail what you are expecting ? To limit the scaling factor to avoid intersection ? To shift instances to remove intersections ?

the simplest solution, the main thing is that there are no intersections between instances with a random value scale, rather move the copies

To shift objects, I would recommend one of the two following posted approaches, in response to Generate non-overlapping spheres having different diameters in a mesh: lemon's and Rumen Belev's.

The simplest solution would be to set the Min Distance in the Poisson Disk distribution to a value as high as the max random radius of an instance. Of course this might leave unnecessary gaps between smaller instances, but how many and how large those gaps are really depend on the actual values you are using, like the range between min and max radius for example.

ok, how to do this, can you send me a screenshot?
